# Google Optimize: Cookie targeting not allowing us to enter variable name

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize

In a Google Optimize experiment, we've targeted a cookie variable named "xpromo".

However, in the running experiment, in targeting under the variable name there is a red error message saying "This variable no longer exists."

We tried copying the experiment, says the same thing.  On the copy, we try to delete the targeting criteria and re-create it.  So we edit the targeting criteria and choose "Create New".  As soon as we type in value for Name your variable of "xpromo", the "Create Variable" button grays out.

On previous attempts, it was saying we could not create this variable because it already existed.

We need to use this variable name, as it is the one used on the site.  Is there anyway to delete / purge this variable name so we can use it again?  It seems like somehow this value got corrupted inside Google Optimize.  Any advice much appreciate, thanks!